# Slow vector tiles off screen canvas rendering with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, web-worker, vector-tiles, offscreen-canvas

There's an example on Openlayers website:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/offscreen-canvas.html

It works fine but when I try to add an additional tile layer (XYZ or WMS) to the map, the rendering process gets drastically slower.

Did anyone solve the problem?

Just tried to add an OSM layer to the map along with the layer from the example which resulted in significantly slowing render.

Comment: Are you adding the layer directly to the map or to layer array in the worker?

Comment: Yes, directly to the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way the code is using `frameState` it might be expecting the worker to do all the rendering and adding another layer directly would conflict with that assumption.  If you must add directly to the map specifying `transition: 0` for the OSM might help.

You could also try adding the OSM to the worker - it will not need `stylefunction` but I think everything else is applicable

```
const layers = [];
const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM({transition: 0})
});
layer.getRenderer().useContainer = function (target, transform) {
  this.containerReused = this.getLayer() !== layers[0];
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.context = context;
  this.container = {
    firstElementChild: canvas,
    style: {
      opacity: layer.getOpacity(),
    },
  };
  rendererTransform = transform;
};
layers.push(layer);
```

Some additional work would be needed as this would need a custom Tile class - Image cannot be used in a worker so it would need to be loaded in the same way as sprites.

**UPDATE**

Ideally OSM could take a tileLoadFunction which loaded the image as a worker compatible imageBitmap in the same way as sprite images:

```
    tileLoadFunction: function (tile, src) {
      const worker = self;
      worker.postMessage({
        action: 'loadImage',
        src: src,
      });
      worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        tile.setImage(event.data.image);
      });
    }
```

Unfortunately the code in ImageTile will still throw an error because it initially tries to create an empty Image without checking if that is supported, so unless that is fixed a custom class will be needed - for example you could copy all the code from https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/ImageTile.js change the class name to ImageBitmapTile and edit any occurrences of `new Image()` to `new Observable()` (imported from `ol/Observable.js` - a simple generic object which accepts listeners)

OSM does not accept a custom tile class so you would need use a TileImage source and specify the OSM url and maxZoom:

```
new TileLayer({
  source: new TileImage({
    url: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    tilegrid: createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
    tileClass: ImageBitMapTile,
    tileLoadFunction: function (tile, src) {
      const worker = self;
      worker.postMessage({
        action: 'loadImage',
        src: src,
      });
      worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        tile.setImage(event.data.image);
      });
    }
  }),
}),
```

I finally got it working with an OSM source simply by defining a dummy `self.Image` at the start of the worker.  The tileLoadFunction must also check that the image returned is the one requested otherwise it picks up images for other tiles, and `renderDeclutter` should only be called for vector layers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.1.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.1.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
     <script>

// inline script used to create worker

const workerScript = () => {

importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.1.0/dist/ol.js')

function stringify(obj, replacer, spaces, cycleReplacer) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj, serializer(replacer, cycleReplacer), spaces)
}
function serializer(replacer, cycleReplacer) {
  var stack = [], keys = []
  if (cycleReplacer == null) cycleReplacer = function(key, value) {
    if (stack[0] === value) return "[Circular ~]"
    return "[Circular ~." + keys.slice(0, stack.indexOf(value)).join(".") + "]"
  }
  return function(key, value) {
    if (stack.length > 0) {
      var thisPos = stack.indexOf(this)
      ~thisPos ? stack.splice(thisPos + 1) : stack.push(this)
      ~thisPos ? keys.splice(thisPos, Infinity, key) : keys.push(key)
      if (~stack.indexOf(value)) value = cycleReplacer.call(this, key, value)
    }
    else stack.push(value)
    return replacer == null ? value : replacer.call(this, key, value)
  }
}

self.Image = EventTarget;

/** @type {any} */
const worker = self;

let frameState, pixelRatio, rendererTransform;
const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(1, 1);
// OffscreenCanvas does not have a style, so we mock it
canvas.style = {};
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const layers = [];
const layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM({
    transition: 0,
    tileLoadFunction: function (tile, src) {
      worker.postMessage({
        action: 'loadImage',
        src: src,
      });
      worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        if (event.data.src == src) {
          tile.setImage(event.data.image);
        }
      });
    }
  }),
});
layer.getRenderer().useContainer = function (target, transform) {
  this.containerReused = this.getLayer() !== layers[0];
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.context = context;
  this.container = {
    firstElementChild: canvas,
    style: {
      opacity: layer.getOpacity(),
    },
  };
  rendererTransform = transform;
};
layers.push(layer);

const maxTotalLoading = 8;
const maxNewLoads = 2;

const tileQueue = new ol.TileQueue(
  (tile, tileSourceKey, tileCenter, tileResolution) =>
  ol.TileQueue.getTilePriority (
      frameState,
      tile,
      tileSourceKey,
      tileCenter,
      tileResolution
    ),
  () => worker.postMessage({action: 'requestRender'})
);

worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {

  if (event.data.action !== 'render') {
    return;
  }
  frameState = event.data.frameState;
  if (!pixelRatio) {
    pixelRatio = frameState.pixelRatio;
  }
  frameState.tileQueue = tileQueue;
  frameState.viewState.projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');
  layers.forEach((layer) => {
    if (ol.layer.Layer.inView(layer.getLayerState(), frameState.viewState)) {
      const renderer = layer.getRenderer();
      renderer.renderFrame(frameState, canvas);
    }
  });
  layers.forEach(
    (layer) => layer.getRenderer().context // && layer.renderDeclutter(frameState)
  );
  if (tileQueue.getTilesLoading() < maxTotalLoading) {
    tileQueue.reprioritize();
    tileQueue.loadMoreTiles(maxTotalLoading, maxNewLoads);
  }
  const imageData = canvas.transferToImageBitmap();
  worker.postMessage(
    {
      action: 'rendered',
      imageData: imageData,
      transform: rendererTransform,
      frameState: JSON.parse(stringify(frameState)),
    },
    [imageData]
  );
});

};

// start of main thread

function stringify(obj, replacer, spaces, cycleReplacer) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj, serializer(replacer, cycleReplacer), spaces)
}
function serializer(replacer, cycleReplacer) {
  var stack = [], keys = []
  if (cycleReplacer == null) cycleReplacer = function(key, value) {
    if (stack[0] === value) return "[Circular ~]"
    return "[Circular ~." + keys.slice(0, stack.indexOf(value)).join(".") + "]"
  }
  return function(key, value) {
    if (stack.length > 0) {
      var thisPos = stack.indexOf(this)
      ~thisPos ? stack.splice(thisPos + 1) : stack.push(this)
      ~thisPos ? keys.splice(thisPos, Infinity, key) : keys.push(key)
      if (~stack.indexOf(value)) value = cycleReplacer.call(this, key, value)
    }
    else stack.push(value)
    return replacer == null ? value : replacer.call(this, key, value)
  }
}
class WebWorker {
  constructor(worker) {
    const code = worker.toString();
    const blob = new Blob(["(" + code + ")()"]);
    return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }
}

// create worker from inline script
const worker = new WebWorker(workerScript);

let container,
  transformContainer,
  canvas,
  rendering,
  workerFrameState,
  mainThreadFrameState;

// Transform the container to account for the difference between the (newer)
// main thread frameState and the (older) worker frameState
function updateContainerTransform() {
  if (workerFrameState) {
    const viewState = mainThreadFrameState.viewState;
    const renderedViewState = workerFrameState.viewState;
    const center = viewState.center;
    const resolution = viewState.resolution;
    const rotation = viewState.rotation;
    const renderedCenter = renderedViewState.center;
    const renderedResolution = renderedViewState.resolution;
    const renderedRotation = renderedViewState.rotation;
    const transform = ol.transform.create();
    // Skip the extra transform for rotated views, because it will not work
    // correctly in that case
    if (!rotation) {
      ol.transform.compose(
        transform,
        (renderedCenter[0] - center[0]) / resolution,
        (center[1] - renderedCenter[1]) / resolution,
        renderedResolution / resolution,
        renderedResolution / resolution,
        rotation - renderedRotation,
        0,
        0
      );
    }
    transformContainer.style.transform = ol.transform.toString(transform);
  }
}

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Layer({
      render: function (frameState) {
        if (!container) {
          container = document.createElement('div');
          container.style.position = 'absolute';
          container.style.width = '100%';
          container.style.height = '100%';
          transformContainer = document.createElement('div');
          transformContainer.style.position = 'absolute';
          transformContainer.style.width = '100%';
          transformContainer.style.height = '100%';
          container.appendChild(transformContainer);
          canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
          canvas.style.left = '0';
          canvas.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
          transformContainer.appendChild(canvas);
        }
        mainThreadFrameState = frameState;
        updateContainerTransform();
        if (!rendering) {
          rendering = true;
          worker.postMessage({
            action: 'render',
            frameState: JSON.parse(stringify(frameState)),
          });
        } else {
          frameState.animate = true;
        }
        return container;
      },
      source: new ol.source.Source({
        attributions: [
          '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
        ],
      }),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    resolutions: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({tileSize: 512}).getResolutions(),
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});

// Worker messaging and actions
worker.addEventListener('message', (message) => {
  if (message.data.action === 'loadImage') {
    // Image loader for ol-mapbox-style
    const image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    image.addEventListener('load', function () {
      createImageBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height).then(
        (imageBitmap) => {
          worker.postMessage(
            {
              action: 'imageLoaded',
              image: imageBitmap,
              src: message.data.src,
            },
            [imageBitmap]
          );
        }
      );
    });
    image.src = message.data.src;
  } else if (message.data.action === 'requestRender') {
    // Worker requested a new render frame
    map.render();
  } else if (canvas && message.data.action === 'rendered') {
    // Worker provides a new render frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      const imageData = message.data.imageData;
      canvas.width = imageData.width;
      canvas.height = imageData.height;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageData, 0, 0);
      canvas.style.transform = message.data.transform;
      workerFrameState = message.data.frameState;
      updateContainerTransform();
    });
    rendering = false;
  }
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, transition: 0 upon the direct layer addition didn't help.

Comment: Adding OSM to the worker results in the following error message:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Image is not defined
    at new ImageTile (ImageTile.js:41:23)
    at OSM.createTile_ (TileImage.js:269:18)
    at OSM.getTileInternal (TileImage.js:363:19)
    at OSM.getTile (TileImage.js:297:19)
    at CanvasTileLayerRenderer.getTile (TileLayer.js:128:27)
    at CanvasTileLayerRenderer.renderFrame (TileLayer.js:323:27)
    at worker.js:184:16
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at worker.js:181:10

It happens on renderer.renderFrame(frameState, canvas); for the OSM layer

Comment: Yes, workers do not support `Image`, ideally OpenLayers should be updated (as has ol-mapbox-style for sprites https://github.com/openlayers/ol-mapbox-style/tree/main#stylefunction) so ImageTile can request an image as an `imageBitmap` if run inside a worker, but in the absence of that a custom tileClass will be needed.

Comment: I have updated the answer with ideas how you could approach that (II am not on a system where I can test it).

Comment: Thank you Mike, now it works like a charm! As far as I understand this approach is also applicable to layers with tile sources such as TileWMS and TileArcGISRest?

Comment: UPDATE: just noticed that the OSM layer always overlaps the Vector Tile one regardless the pushing order and zIndex (